# General direction rails external API

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a rails app that uses the Edmunds external API. http://developer.edmunds.com/

On the home page I am trying to create a dynamic select dropdown box. Here is the sequence of events.

1) On Home page load, a select dropdown is populated with all new car *makes* (Toyota, Honda etc.)

2) When a user chooses a specific car make, a second select dropdown appears with the list of all the car *models* specific to the make. (Camry, Accord etc.)

3) The same sequence occurs for the specific trim and style of the car. The end result is a specific car( Toyota Camry LE 2DR).

4) The user clicks the submit button and the attributes of the car are saved to the Car model with the same corresponding attributes.

I am looking for a high level overview of the best way to go about this.

Currently, I have the dynamic select box behavior working correctly. The problem is that it's all Jquery and makes an AJAX call every time a new make is selected.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/makes?fmt=json&state=new&api_key=" + edmunds_api_key,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
    var makeArray = data.makes;
    console.log(data.makes);
    $.each(makeArray, function(index, value) {
      $('#make_id').append('<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
    });
  }
});

$(document).on('change', '#make_id', function() {
  retrieve_model(this.value);
});

function retrieve_model(make) {
  $.get('https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/' + make + '/models?  fmt=json&api_key=' + edmunds_api_key, function(data) {
    var modelArray = data.models;
    console.log(data.models);
    $('#model_id').empty();
    $.each(modelArray, function(index, value) {
      $('#model_id').append('<option>' + value.name + '</option>');
    });
  });
}
```

I know that there is a better way to do this. I'm just not sure how to do it or what the best practices are when implementing this sort of application.

Looking for general guidance on how one would go about a project as described.

On the Home page load, can I make 1 call and then use that data throughout? Rather than making multiple unnecessary calls.

I did find many previous posts about this topic. Such as.. [Using ActiveRecord interface for Models backed by external API in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313535/using-activerecord-interface-for-models-backed-by-external-api-in-ruby-on-rails?rq=1)

Most were either over my head or for older versions of Rails. Any advice?

Comment: Can you be more clear on your objectives - are you trying to avoid hits to the Edumnds API? Are you trying to make it faster? If it's slow, what part is slow? if you take a look at the edmunds.com site, they make a AJAX request every time a user picks a model, but they cache the response on the browser so the second time you request the same model, the data is returned a little faster.

Comment: I want the select drop down to dynamically generate and to save the result to the database. I am new and am unsure whether it is appropriate to make that many requests to an external API. Is my all Jquery solution acceptable or is a solution that involves rails controllers/models better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check your API license and calculate anticipated volume - they probably throttle you to x connections / second/hour. If you can live within those limitations I don't see any reason not to use the API. You can put in place some common sense caching to prevent unnecessary calls (untested):

```
$(document).on('change', '#make_id', function() {
  writeModels(retrieve_model(this.value));
});

var modelCache = {};

function retrieve_model(make) {
  if (modelCache[make]) {
    return modelCache[make]; //return cached value
  }
  $.get('https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/' + make + '/models?  fmt=json&api_key=' + edmunds_api_key, { 
    context: this,  //needed to ensure "make" is correct in the complete callback
    complete: function(data) {
      var modelArray = data.models;
      console.log(data.models);
      modelCache[make] = data.models; //populate cache
    }
  });
}

function writeModels(modelArray) {
  $('#model_id').empty();
  $.each(modelArray, function(index, value) {
    $('#model_id').append('<option>' + value.name + '</option>');
  });
}
```